# VS Code - Turn off auto close tags, but leave on autocomplete

Tags: visual-studio-code

Recently switched from Sublime Text 3 to VS Code. Overall pleased with the switch except for this one little thing that's just annoying enough to be a dealbreaker if there's no solution. In ST3 if I type, say, a `<div>`, it doesn't automatically drop in a `</div>`, which is nice because I'm often pasting it in and don't want it closed right there.

What ST3 DOES do, however, is complete the tag the moment I type `</`. It autofills `div>` the moment I type the forward slash. This is the behavior I want from VS Code. I can't find any mention of this anywhere which is completely baffling. I know how to autoclose tags, but that's no good becasue then I have to manually close them. I want VS Code, like ST3, to autocomplete the tag for me, just not immediately.

Answer (score 64):

Go to **File > Preferences > Settings**, search for `html.autoClosingTags` and set it to `false`.

This will make it so when you type `<div>`, it won't insert `</div>` automatically, but if you start typing `</`, it won't close the tag automatically. You can press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to make it autocomplete for you.

Or you can leave this option enabled and when you type `<div>` and it autocompletes, you can just press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>.

More information on this behavior [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/html#_close-tags).

Comment: Hitting enter isn't a big deal, but it is still an extra keystroke needed for every single tag I want to close. Thanks for helping, but I'm completely amazed that there isn't an actual solution for this given VS Code's customizability.

Comment: You mean:   Go to "Code > Preferences > Settings..."

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that for those working in JSX you also should disable it in JavaScript (`javascript.autoClosingTags`) and TypeScript (`typescript.autoClosingTags`).

Comment: Agreed; you should not have to hit Enter. I thought that maybe it's in case you have two or more tags open (e.g., <p><span>...) so you can select which one you want to autoclose. But nope! It only gives you the most recently used tag as an option every single time. Pointless!

Answer (score 4):

Add this to settings.json to make it work like Sublime Text:

```
"html.autoClosingTags": false,
"auto-close-tag.SublimeText3Mode": true
```

Comment: `"auto-close-tag.SublimeText3Mode"` is not built-in. It comes with the [Auto Close Tag](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.auto-close-tag) extension.

Answer (score 4):

Go to Settings, search for "auto closing" and enable/disable these options as needed

[image: Auto closing settings in VS Code]

Or set them in your settings.json file like so:

```
"html.autoClosingTags": false,
"typescript.autoClosingTags": false,
"javascript.autoClosingTags": false,
```

Answer (score 1):

On Windows/Linux - Ctrl + Shift + P

On MacOS - Cmd + Shift + P

In the search box type settings.json

paste the following line there

`"html.autoClosingTags": false`

Answer (score 0):

#### A very simple trick i learnt

If you want to disable tags auto completion for just a single task for example. To save a file without vscode adding closing tags. Just set a different `language mode` for that file.
Change from the inferred one i.e `html` to `Batch`, `Diff` `ignore`. The options on vscode are many. This will enable you to save the file without addition of any closing tags.
After you are remember to reset the language mode to `Auto Detect`.

**TLDR;**
To access language mode-:

- Use the command pallete and search `Change Language Mode` or
- Find a shortcut at the bottom right section on Vscode.